# How does one query the Ethereum ENS name service via an API endpoint with a JSON response?

Tags: addresses, ens, dns, eth-domain

Using the https://ens.domains/ is there a way to query the ENS name service using an API endpoint and get a JSON response? I want to be able to integrate these eth addresses into my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cindercloud](https://cinder.cloud) has a rest-endpoint which is specifically designed for this.

[Documentation on this endpoint can be found here](https://rapidapi.com/Qkyrie/api/cindercloud?endpoint=apiendpoint_d4739065-87e4-46fd-b8d8-55f7a9caf42b).

Comment: that requires signing up for that service. https://etherscan.io/enslookup -- etherscan has a free lookup tool, but i'm not sure how to output the json api

Comment: Instead of using the rapidapi endpoint, you can also use https://api.cinder.cloud. It's rate limited, but free.

Comment: Looks like you own that api restpoint, hence the bias. thanks anyways. I want to just do a simple call to retrieve what a .eth domain resolves to. why is it so difficult to do?

Comment: I do indeed. It's not that difficult, it's just calling the ENSResolver contract on chain with the correct data, but you asked for an API endpoint which returns a json result and I happen to have something like that, which is why I proposed it as a solution :)

Comment: Do I need to install any other js libraries or sign up for some token key id?

Comment: You can use api free of use, with certain rate-limitations. For a way higher rate, you can sign up on rapidapi for an api key. No extra library is required to use the rest api

Comment: I hope you did not take Qkyrie's advice and use his API because it is gone now. Never use an amateur API for crypto. Use something stable you trust. Why not use the API from ENS directly: https://docs.ens.domains/

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but this was the first result on Google. Since 2019, Cloudflare now hosts a free Ethereum web resolver. You can read more here: https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-distributed-web-resolver/

The ethers.js project is a fantastic, easy to use, web-ready Ethereum client that supports many providers, one of which being a CloudflareProvider (https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/api-providers/#CloudflareProvider)

So resolving an ENS address to a wallet address is now as easy as:

**(Last updated November 22, 2023)**

1. Install ethers.js, with npm for example:

```
npm install ethers
```

2. Import the module:

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers'
```

3. Resolve:

```
const provider = new ethers.CloudflareProvider()
const address = await provider.resolveName('vitalik.eth')
console.log(address)

// Outputs 0xd8dA6BF26964aF9D7eEd9e03E53415D37aA96045
```

Happy coding :)